# Excel macro to distribute data from one column in Sheet1 to several columns in Sheet2 alphabetically

Tags: excel, vba

We have a workbook of two sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2. 
In Sheet1, there's only one column that contains data of nearly 1 million cells (names of products). 
Sheet2 has existing data (also names of products) where the first row is reserved for the alphabetic column headers; A-Z and NUM (27 cols).
What we're after is a macro that will sort data in Sheet1 a-z0-9, and then distribute (move) each letter's chunk of data from Sheet1 to the bottom of data of each designated column of the letter in Sheet2.
We have actually searched for similar solutions in many forums that we can adopt and adapt, but we basically did not find any.Can anyone help us please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us the code you have written, or started to write, and we'll help you fix it or improve it...

Comment: Thank you Philip for your promptness, but actually we don't have any code that we can build upon.

Comment: we don't write code, we help developers improve code or fix error or problems

Comment: No worries, I will do my homework to find similar code, which we can build upon. as soon as I get it I will post it here. thank Philip, I'm actually still learning how to use StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to have a play with. 
Just drop it into an empty workbook and:

- run createRandomStrings()
- *manually sort the items in Sheet1.ColumnA*
- then run tmp()

It should give you an idea to work with.

You can easily record a sort in progress to get the code for that.

```
Sub createRandomStrings()
    Dim curRow, curStr, curLtr, i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For curRow = 1 To 50000
        curStr = ""
        For i = 0 To 10
            curChar = Int((Asc("Z") - Asc("A") + 1) * Rnd + Asc("A"))
            curStr = curStr + Chr(curChar)
        Next i
        Cells(curRow, 1) = curStr
    Next curRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function findFirstItemStartingWith(startLetter) As Integer
    Dim curRow, curStr ', startLetter ** EDIT ** this var commented-out

    For curRow = 1 To 50000
        curStr = Cells(curRow, 1)
        If Mid(curStr, 1, 1) = startLetter Then
            findFirstItemStartingWith = curRow
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next curRow
    findFirstItemStartingWith = -1
End Function

Sub tmp()
    aStart = findFirstItemStartingWith("A")
    bStart = findFirstItemStartingWith("B")
    If (aStart <> -1) And (bStart <> -1) Then
        MsgBox ("A found from Row: " + Str(aStart) + " to " + Str(bStart - 1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I really don't know what to say as thanking is not enough Enhzflep. You saved days for me by posting this script; thank you very very much. I will run it and feed you back. All the best.

Comment: No worries. :-) Consider it said. Its just experience, hope it helps you to gather a little more.

Comment: Well, I created random strings and manually sorted them in Sheet1.ColumnA, and as I ran sub tmp(), I got a "Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope" highlighting "StartLetter" variable defined in Function findFirstItemStartingWith(startLetter) As Integer in second line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh. oops, sorry. Just remove the variable (or rename it) I was going to use it to make a function that would find the first & last row of entries beginning with the same letter. Keep the one in the function signature though, _that_ one is used. I'll update the code in a second.